# Pass in date params to Facebook batch request

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-batch-request

I want to pass in date parameters into the PHP SDK batch request method.

Is it possible to pass in date params such as:

```
$params = array(
  'time_range' => array(
    'since' => (new \DateTime("-1 week"))->format('Y-m-d'),
    'until' => (new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d'),
  ),
);
```

My batch request is essentially:

```
foreach( $campaign_ids as $campaign_id ) {  

    $batch[] = $fb->request('GET/', env("FB_APP_VERSION") . '/' . $campaign_id . '/insights?fields=impressions,unique_clicks,reach');    

}

    try {
      $responses = $fb->sendBatchRequest($batch);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the source code, I found you can pass the date through in params as such: (it gets url_encoded when passed to the request handler)

```
foreach( $campaigns as $campaign ) {  

        $params = array(
          'time_range' => array(
            'since' => (new \DateTime($campaign->data_date . ' -1 day'))->format('Y-m-d'),
            'until' => (new \DateTime($campaign->data_date))->format('Y-m-d')
          ),
        );

        $batch[] = $fb->request('GET', '/' . $campaign->ad_campaign_id . '/insights?fields=impressions,unique_clicks,reach', $params);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/v2.5#dates-and-time

I'd assume you can add an additionial paramenter to each request like this:

Format: `time_range={'since':'2015-01-01','until':'2015-01-20'}`

In PHP, this would mean you's have to [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode) the `$params` array and add it to each request.

```
$time_range = array(
    'since' => (new \DateTime("-1 week"))->format('Y-m-d'),
    'until' => (new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d'),
)

$fb->request('GET/', env("FB_APP_VERSION") . '/' . $campaign_id . '/insights?fields=impressions,unique_clicks,reach&time_range=' . json_encode($time_range));
```